# Nature of Singularity in $\dfrac{1-\exp(z) }{ 1+ \exp(z) }$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

What is nature of Singularity in $\dfrac{1-\exp(z) }{ 1+ \exp(z) }$? From this we'll get, $\exp(z)= -1$. How can I to proceed further?

Comment: $e^z=-1\implies e^z=e^{i(2n+1)\pi}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks. Is this essential singularity ?

Comment: No.  These are simple poles.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.